# Spacing before the arrow using groupRowRenderer

Tags: ag-grid

I made by own groupRowRenderer and it works nicely, but just like in the example with the flags [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/), there is very little white space between the arrow (>) and the window border.  I'd like a bit more white space just like the other examples in that same page.  I suppose I could edit a class to give it some padding? Which one?  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're link doesn't goto a specific example of course, but one with flags I found.. You want to add padding to the left of the > that is in you're custom renderer.

Inspecting their example, adding 10px for example seemed to work to the following class.

`::ng-deep ag-icon ag-icon-contracted {
    padding-left: 10px;
}`

Apologies if I didn't understand correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  I tried changing that class, but that not adding any space.  It seems to work when NOT using groupRowInnerRenderer, but I do want to make my own renderer.  I just don't seem to have control over the arrow.

Comment: try adding the ::ng-deep

Comment: no luck.  It has no effect whatsoever.  I'm able to change other CSS classes without problem.  This is one just doesn't seem to work.